# PHP search form filters using multiple drop down

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, filter

Here is revised code. Still no luck ! pls. help

```
<html>
<body>

<?php

 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "test");

 $whereClauses = '';
 $numLocations = count($_POST['Locations']);
 $numJobs = count($_POST['Jobs']);
 $i = 0;
 if (! empty($_POST['Locations'])) {
  foreach ($_POST['locations'] as $location) {
    $whereClauses .="Locations='".mysql_real_escape_string($location)."'";
    if ($i++ == $numLocations) {
     $whereClauses .= " AND";
    }
  }
  }
  if (! empty($_POST['Jobs'])) {
  foreach ($_POST['Jobs'] as $job) {
    $whereClauses .="Jobs='".mysql_real_escape_string($job)."'";
  }
  if ($i++ == $numJobs) {
     $whereClauses .= " AND";
  }
   }
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable '".$whereClauses."' ORDER BY id DESC '".$limit."'";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['Locations'];
echo $row['Jobs'];
}

?>
 </body>
</html>
```

===============================================
I created a HTML and PHP file to filter web form data based on multiple drop down filters. Here goes the form. When I run the form and PHP, I don't see any results in the browser. There is no error either. I'm working on an example posted by another forum member.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
<form action="showJobs_new.php" method="post">
<select name="Locations">
<option value="" selected="selected">All Locations</option>
<option value="arizona">Arizona</option>
<option value="alaska">Alaska</option>
</select>
<select name="Jobs">
<option value="" selected="selected">All jobs</option>
<option value="Carpenter">Carpenters</option>
<option value="Plumbers">Plumbers</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="search jobs" />
</form>

showJobs_new.php:

<html>
<body>

<?php

$username="root";
$password="password";
$database="test";

mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$whereClauses = array(); 
if (! empty($_POST['Locations'])) $whereClauses[] ="Locations='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Locations'])."'"; 
if (! empty($_POST['Jobs'])) $whereClauses[] ="Jobs='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Jobs'])."'"; 
$where = ''; 
if (count($whereClauses) > 0) { $where = ' WHERE '.implode(' AND ',$whereClauses); } 

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC $limit" .$where);  

$result=mysql_query($sql);
or die("Error: ".mysql_error()."<br />Query: ".$sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo $row['Locations'];
echo $row['Jobs'];
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you "run the form and PHP"?

Comment: I will put them in 2 separate files, 1 .html for form and php for processing.

Comment: as an aside, the mysql extension that you are using is old and no longer recommended (http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) Try mysqli or pdo extensions instead.

Comment: thanks dnagirl. I changed that part. any other suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

Change the query to

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable " .$where." ORDER BY id DESC $limit");
```

The order of the query seems to be wrong.

Comment: thanks both for help. I corrected that part. Still no display and no error either :(

Comment: You are using mysql_query() function twice in your code. please remove the second mysql_query() function.

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC $limit" .$where);  

$result=mysql_query($sql);// remove this line... and use the $sql inside the mysql_fetch_assoc() function

Answer (score 1):

Hi dear You have two errors in query.

1-this is because you are putting wrong clause order. You need to learn what is the priority of clauses in query. When you run query, order of clause should look like

- Select
- From
- Where
- Group by
- Having
- Order BY
- Limit

2- using mysql_query two times as suggested by `user1599669`

So your query should looks like

```
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable $where ORDER BY id DESC $limit");
```

For more reference read from [mysql dev](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).